# Visual Basic Editor - Excel - Dates- Help Wanted

Tags: excel, vba

Visual Basic Editor - Help Wanted

I have a spreadsheet that has 3 columns with different due dates I am looking to send an automatic email when either of the dates expire within 30 days. Currently the code I have is only pulling from one column is there a way for it to look at all three columns?

Example
John Smith's license is due on March 13 (column D), his passport is due on May 12 (column E) and his car registration is due on March 19 (column F) the code I have written will only pull from/look at column D and will only send an email based on that column - based on the expiration information it should send an email based on column D and column F

This is the current code I have

```
toDate = Replace(Cells(i, 4), ".", "/")
```

How can I code it to look at all 3 columns

Comment: Change the `column` parameter to reflect the column you want to examine.  Perhaps in a loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The number 4 in your code represents which column you are looking at, so just create some more variables and change the number, like this:

```
toDateD = Replace(Cells(i, 4), ".", "/")
toDateE = Replace(Cells(i, 5), ".", "/")
toDateF = Replace(Cells(i, 6), ".", "/")
```

See the pattern?

There are other ways to do it too... I prefer this way:

```
toDateD = Replace(Range("D" & i), ".", "/")
toDateE = Replace(Range("E" & i), ".", "/")
toDateF = Replace(Range("F" & i), ".", "/")
```

See how that is more readable for debugging?

Comment: Thanks for the insight...YOU ARE AWESOME.  It worked perfectly.

Comment: Thanks for the insight...YOU ARE AWESOME. It worked perfectly